# Getting json data from a nested array

Tags: javascript, json, api, nested

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around some JSON stuff. Namely, I'm trying to retrieve a string from a json response received from the google translate api i'm querying.

```
  var translator = function () {
  for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
  {
    //Construct URI
    var source =
      'https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?' +
      'key=MY-API-KEY-REMOVED-ON-PURPOSE&' +
      'source=en&' +
      'target=fr&' +
      'q=' +
      result[i][1]; //looping over an array, no problem there



      //Receive response from server
    var to_Translate =new XMLHttpRequest();
    to_Translate.open("GET",source,false);
    to_Translate.send();
    var translated = to_Translate.responseText;

    JSON.parse(translated);
    translated = translated.data.translations[0].translatedText;

    console.log(translated);


  }
};


translator();
```

Where

```
console.log(translated);
```

yields

```
 {
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {
    "translatedText": "some stuff that's been translated"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

My question is: how can i access the value of translatedText? I've tried:

```
translated.data.translations[0].translatedText;
```

But it doesn't seem to work. When I console.log this i get

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'translations' of undefined 
    translator 
(anonymous function)
```

Let me know what you guys think!

Comment: Guys I've just edited my question. I've added your guys suggestions but i'm still getting a slight problem...

Comment: I've edited my answer, now you should get the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is just text you have to parse it with

```
JSON.parse(translated)
```

so you could access it with, for example, `translated.data`

UPDATE

The error you are getting means that `translated.data` is undefined, you have to assign the parse to a variable, otherwise it will never work, it doesn't modify it in place

```
var translated = JSON.parse(to_Translate.responseText);
```

Comment: Thanks Alberto! I've used your suggestion, but i'm still getting an error in the console. Any idea? Thanks so much!

Comment: It works like a charm, many thanks! I'm 2 reputation points short of being able to upvote an answer... But I could if you upvote my question. Sorry for the haggling haha! Anyway thank you so much alberto!

Answer (score 0):

So close!

```
translated.data.translations[0].translatedText;
```

`translations` is an array of objects, and you want the `translatedText` property of the first element in the array.

**UPDATE**:

Just to confirm the output of `to_Translate.responseText` is a string containing:

```
{
 "data": {
  "translations": [
   {   
    "translatedText": "some stuff that's been translated"
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

So you should be able to do:

```
var translated = to_Translate.responseText,
    parsed = JSON.parse(translated),
    text = parsed.data.translations[0].translatedText;

console.log(text);
```

Comment: Hey @Jon you're totally right. I had tried that also but i had the console error I just uploaded in my question. Any idea? Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Use
 `translated.data.translations[0].translatedText;`

Hope it will work fine.